# Perl equivalent to Kornshell export command?

Tags: perl, export, ksh

I'm working on translating some kornshell to perl and was wondering if there is an equivalent in perl to export

Comment: `$ENV[VARNAME} = "value";`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `$ENV{`

Comment: @choroba: Aargh — yes, it is supposed to be symmetrically using braces `{}`, as in `$ENV{VARNAME} = "value";`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very straight-forward.  The `%ENV` hash contains the values of the environment variables keyed by environment variable name.  You can set or update an environment variable's value by assigning to `%ENV`:

```
$ENV{VARNAME} = "value";
```

or:

```
my $varname = "VARNAME";
my $value = "value";
$ENV{$varname} = $value;
```

You can delete an environment variable in Perl with:

```
delete $ENV{VARNAME};
```

---

> And in `ksh` this would correspond to "`export varname=value`"?

These examples are both equivalent to the (Korn, Bash, Bourne) shell notation:

```
export VARNAME="value"
```

or, if you're stretching the limits a bit, the second is equivalent to:

```
varname="VARNAME"
value="value"
export $varname="$value"
```

Comment: and in ksh this would correspond to "export varname = value" ?

Comment: @qwerty12345: see update, but (give or take spacing around the `=` sign), the answer is "yes".